# Paypal payment in app, how to clear previous user paypal data?

Tags: java, android, paypal

Good Sunday to everybody :)
I thought it was an easy question but I cannot find any clean solution.
I have succesfully implemented Paypal integration within my app, of course at the moment I am using Sandbox.
By the way now I am testing my app, and OUCH! When logging out with a user, switching to another, when purchasing something, previous paypal user data are still prompted in the Paypal embedded (and non changeable) page.
Now, I could do it the hard way: deleting all the cache dir within my app, but I am pretty sure it is a brutal solution and not so clean after all.
Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easy way as of today!  Just use the static [`PayPalService.clearAllUserData()`](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalService.html#clearAllUserData%28android.content.Context%29) method to clear all the user's info.

Comment: I'll tell you what. Stackoverflow is AMAZING. More helpful than the dumbass support center inside every company that should be committed and own all the knowhow (since they are the ones who release the software...)
Well I made this very question to the PayPal support, and even this time they showed themselves as ignorant and useless. Your answer is right, I checked and I was using 2.8.8 SDK version, this useful method has been added in the 2.9.0, that now I imported.
Thumbs upp for you and stackoverflow, Thumbs VERY down for the dumb and useless customer cares.
Thank you so much

Comment: @Bies, apologies for your experience with our customer support.  Given that this feature was developed over the weekend, and released yesterday, I think we can cut them a little slack.  For future reference, feel free to use our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) for quicker responses.

Comment: Thanks again. In the end, even if I imported the android support libraries (compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0' in the gradle file), the method PayPalService.clearAllUserData(getApplicationContext()) does not do anything, even a Warning or something in the logat. Could you possibily help?

Comment: You're saying the method does not clear the user data?  Keep in mind it only clears the data for the currently set environment.  If you're switching between environments, you may notice the different behavior.

Comment: I am using for testing always the same device, if that is what you are suggesting.
Here the code:
PayPalService.clearAllUserData(getApplicationContext());
This is called in the settings activities, and executed at the disconnectFromUser() custom command in my app

Comment: Hmm.  Is the PayPalService still running, or did you stop the service prior to calling this method?  The service must still be running to receive the message to clear the data.

Comment: Sorry if i keep answering here but I don't have enough rep for chat :(
So this is the problem... but I don't understand, I stop the Service in the ondestroy() method of the activity which starts the payment process.
I need to clear data when a user decide to log out, and the Service is not started. I mean, when i do the                                                                 
                               startService(intentpaypal);                          

the PayPal activity is started, and for sure I don't want that to happen when I log out.
I hope I am missing something -_-'

Comment: That makes sense, and I did not consider this case.  A workaround for now is to start the PayPalService when you start your app, and just leave it running.  I'll post here when a more robust solution is released.

Comment: In the meanwhile I opened an issue on GitHub explaining better the case, as you suggested. I hope this is not a problem. (In the meanwhile I won't be making the service run free in my recipient device, so I will come back to the force delete my app's cache files )

Comment: By the way your workaround should not work: 1) if I start the service for example in my Launcher Activity, it would open the payment page (not wanted) 2) if I launch it when I launch it now and i decide not to stop that in the onDestroy() method of the caller activity, then I would get errors the second time I try to make a Payment because it would start twice an already running service. Am I wrong?

Comment: The workaround works if you leave the service running at all times.  No need to start the service for each payment.

Comment: And how could I make that without prompting the Paypal Activity when I start it at the very first time?

Comment: Just don't launch the PayPalActivity!  Starting the service and starting the activity are two separate commands.  :)

Comment: Oh well, so my mistake was thinking that startService(intentpp) opens also the PayPal Activity, I checked my code and it is the startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT); that does it. So ok, with the service running it works fine... but, again, if I could I would choose not to have the Service always running, it is a waste of resources, I think you would agree

Comment: Last reply, I promise. It seems that even if the Service is up & running, the clearAllUserData() only works if I close the app and reopen it.
If I just log in with another user with the app still open it would keep the previous user data. I am pretty sure this is a replicable issue. Bug?